# Mongoose web server not processing HTTP requests in a non-blocking manner

Tags: c++, mongoose-web-server

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>

#include "mongoose.h"

static void fn(struct mg_connection *c, int ev, void *ev_data, void *fn_data) {
    if (ev == MG_EV_HTTP_MSG) {
        std::cout << "Received HTTP request\n";
        // mg_http_reply(c, 200, "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n", "Hello, %s\n", "world");
    }
}

int main() {
    struct mg_mgr mgr;
    mg_mgr_init(&mgr);
    mg_log_set("3");
    mg_http_listen(&mgr, "0.0.0.0:29906", fn, NULL);              // Create listening connection
    for (;;) mg_mgr_poll(&mgr, 1000);  // Block forever
}
```

This is the minimal "Dynamic RESTful server" from the [Mongoose web server](https://mongoose.ws/tutorials/http-server/) tutorial section, however, I have commented out the section of code which causes it to reply to requests, and replaced it with a console message "Received HTTP request".

On [its Github page](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose), Mongoose claims that it is event-driven and non-blocking. However, when I run this code and send the server three concurrent HTTP requests, I receive the following output:

```
2022-02-14 05:44:35 3 mongoose.c:3569:mg_listen  1 accepting on 0.0.0.0:29906 (port 29906)
2022-02-14 05:44:37 3 mongoose.c:3467:accept_con 2 accepted 127.0.0.1:52957
Received HTTP request
2022-02-14 05:44:38 3 mongoose.c:3467:accept_con 3 accepted 127.0.0.1:52958
2022-02-14 05:44:44 3 mongoose.c:3170:iolog      2   00100000000010 0:0 -1 err 0
2022-02-14 05:44:44 3 mongoose.c:3353:close_conn 2 closed
Received HTTP request
2022-02-14 05:44:45 3 mongoose.c:3170:iolog      3   00100000000010 0:0 -1 err 0
2022-02-14 05:44:45 3 mongoose.c:3353:close_conn 3 closed
2022-02-14 05:44:45 3 mongoose.c:3467:accept_con 4 accepted 127.0.0.1:52961
Received HTTP request
2022-02-14 05:44:45 3 mongoose.c:3467:accept_con 5 accepted 127.0.0.1:52962
2022-02-14 05:44:47 3 mongoose.c:3170:iolog      4   00100000000010 0:0 -1 err 0
2022-02-14 05:44:47 3 mongoose.c:3353:close_conn 4 closed
```

The server tries to process the first request, waits for it to timeout, then tries to process the second request, waits for it to timeout...

My question is, how can I prevent this from occurring, and allow the processing of HTTP requests in a non-blocking manner (i.e. they would all show "Received HTTP request" at the same time)?

Comment: i know nothing about mongoose but it doesnt say that its non blocking , just that it has non blocking io / network handlers. Maybe that means that while you are reading or writing it can run another request (like node), but you are not doing that

Comment: I mean, you can look in the code to see what it is doing. I used the mongoose codebase professionally like a decade ago ... at that time the way the code worked was with a thread pool implemented using pthreads and condition variables.